# Numpy faster than pure C?

Tags: python, c, performance, numpy, time

I have the following C code. On my machine, I clock this in at around 13 seconds.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    clock_t begin = clock();

    double d = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) {
        d = 1 + rand() * 5 > 10 ? 4 : rand();
    }

    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double) (end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("%f", time_spent);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But this numpy operation, I clock at fractions of a second!

```
a = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)
b = np.random.randn(1000, 1000)
c = a.dot(b)
```

How is this possible, given that they're doing the same amount (1e9 operations) of work? Is numpy parallelizing??

Comment: What OS are you running on? If you're on Linux, run the `top` command from the command line while running the numpy operation, and visually check how many cores are being used. Although I suspect numpy isn't using parallelism without you explicitly telling it to do so.

Comment: Your C program effectively has an `if` in the middle - that often stalls a CPU.

Comment: You are doing very different operations. For one thing, your Python is generating 2e6 pseudorandom numbers; your C code, at least 1e9 in addition to the multiply-and-sum that both codes are doing. Would you rather lift a thousand pieces of paper or a thousand cannon balls? Why? Isn't it the same, thousand and thousand?

Comment: try doing **np.random.randn(31623, 31623)**

Comment: In c you are doing more than 10^9 rand() operations, because of your condition in the loop.

Comment: This again... It is completely and utterly pointless to discuss performance if 1) you don't tell us which system you use, 2) you don't tell us which compiler you use, and 3) you don't tell us which optimization options that where used.

Comment: @Lundin: Your claim that it is pointless to discuss performance without that information is contradicted by the fact the primary cause of the behavior OP observed was correctly diagnosed two hours prior to your comment.

Answer (score 6):

Your pragrams are not doing the same. Your `C` program calls `rand` *at least* `10^9` times. additionally you have conditions on your randoms.

`numpy` creates 2 `1000x1000` arrays which is `2x10^6` only. no conditions on the random value. the dot product then adds `O(n^3)` operations (and an array creation) but is very optimized.

So you are basically comparing sequential `rand` calls in `C` to much fewer `randn` calls plus an optimized operation (`dot`) in python.

in order to have a valid benchmark you should have 2 programs that are doing the exact same operations.

Comment: Are you implying that the numpy program only makes 1 call to a random function to generate 10^6 distinct random entries?

Comment: Matrix dot product takes O(n^3), which is 1e9.

Comment: But the dot is along the shared dimension of 1000. So we have two arrays at 10^6, I'm with you. But the dot adds another 10^3 operations. Back at 10^9

Comment: Numpy likely highly optimizes the dot product for cache locality, so I'd be willing to wager its 10^9 operations execute much more quickly than the 10^9 system calls (for random) in the C++ program.

Comment: you are still comparing *very* different operations. `~10^9` `rand()` calls vs `10^6` `nrand()` calls plus multiplications/array creation. for a real benchmark you should make sure your programs do exactly the same.

Comment: @Arthur-1 `random` is not a system call.

Comment: Note that both codes do 1e9 additions and 1e9 multiplications, unconditionally. The cca 2e9 `rand` calls are _on top_ of that. [Here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/random_r.c.html#__random_r)'s the source of glibc random - an addition, a multiplication and a bitwise AND (for the simplest RNG).

Comment: Silly me, I don't know why on earth I'd assume the implementation would make a syscall to the os's random number generator. Probably time to sleep :)

Comment: `numpy.dot` will call an underlying BLAS library on your system if possible

Answer (score -4):

Numpy has backends in multiple languages like C, C++, and Fortran as listed [on their docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/c-info.python-as-glue.html)

> As Numeric has matured and developed into NumPy, people have been able
>   to write more code directly in NumPy. Often this code is fast-enough
>   for production use, but there are still times that there is a need to
>   access compiled code. Either to get that last bit of efficiency out of
>   the algorithm or to make it easier to access widely-available codes
>   written in C/C++ or Fortran)

So unless you're writing highly optimized C code chances are it'll be slower anyways